# call page without loading

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I am working in a C# code behind file.  Basically what is going on is that I am trying to keep the data between two session, one classic asp one .net in parallel.  If the language choice from the .net session is updated I want to call the page update_lang.asp page and pass it the users new language choice.  I do not want to pass control to this page, nor do I want to load it, I just simply want it to 'run' and update the necessary session variable, how do I call the page.

My first thought was session.transfer() but this transfers control, I want the current page to continue running, any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: are you calling the ASP page from ASP.NET or the ASP.NET page from ASP page? in witch platform will you call the other?

Comment: I am calling the classic asp page from the .net page.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the WebClient (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx). It allows you to open any webpage, so you could easily open your ASP file.

```
public void LoadPage()
{
    string DestinationUrl = ".../file.asp";
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();

    string data = "Some data";

    //String s = wc.UploadString(DestinationUrl, data);
    String s = wc.UploadStringAsync(DestinationUrl, data);
}
```

Small sidenote: Although it may be possible, it sounds like a real hacky solution.. Maybe you could look for a more solid way...

**Edit**

As Balexandre points out, it is better to do a Async-call, if you don't need to wait on the result. This way, the call won't block the thread.

Comment: Pbirkoff, yes but this is only a temporary measure until we have updated the site to be fully .net.

Comment: remember to use the async call to avoid the main thread to stop waiting for something... unless you really need it.

Comment: @Pbirkoff you should always use the `using` keyword when an object implements `IDisposable` interface... or at least, end with `wc.Dispose();`

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, the call was made but it was obvious that the page was not being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Make an http web request:

```
HttpWebRequest myReq =
   (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.mypage.com/");
WebResponse myResponse = myReq.GetResponse();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could inject javascript into the page that makes an AJAX call to the configuration page in question.

This would cause the user's machine to make the call if that is preferable.